# How to test Internet Explorer 9 on a Mac OSX Machine?

Tags: internet-explorer, macos, internet-explorer-9

It's possible to test IE6-8 on Mac OSX via free virtual machines that microsoft offers and then running them in something like VMWare Fusion. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en

However, the IE9 image does not seem to be out yet. Does anyone know anyways which we can test it on a Mac OSX machine?

Comment: I would not recommend this, either run it in a virtual machine or use bootcamp, if you use something like wine I can assure you it won't give you the same experience as it would on a VM or windows machine -- hardware acceleration

Comment: @Antwan I agree, wine is a bad solution. That's why I didn't mention it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not surprised the free virtual machine isn't out yet for 9... it's been about 24 hours since release.

Are these free VPC images somehow locked down to not let you install anything else?  If not, take one and install 9 on it.

With regards to Fusion, you'd obviously have to run these VPC images thru a converter and then it's not guaranteed to work (from text found at the link).

Comment: Thanks Jason. I tried to use the Vista image Microsoft provides, but it just kept giving me bluescreens in both VirtualBox and VMWare Fusion. My solution now is to just grab a copy of Windows 7 IE8 and install IE9 on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see how a website would look on IE9, you can use [Adobe's BrowserLab](http://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html). It can be used to test how a website looks in different browsers side-by-side.